# PayflowPro Recurring Billing - How To Update Payment Info in Subscription Profile

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-nvp

When using PayPal Advanced, the API allows the creation of a subscription profile by converting a single payment (using PNREF as ORIGID).
We are testing this using the embedded IFRAME to capture CC information. (Sandbox & Test Accounts).
Now, in the PayflowPro Recurring billing API - December 2012 documentation the "MODIFY" action is explained.  We have tested this (MODIFY) action for most subscription parameters.
How can we update the PAYMENT information, say user wants to use a diff CC, for whatever reason.  Since the original info was captured by PP using the embedded IFRAME, we do not keep payment info on-record at our system. One reason to use PP-Advanced is so we do NOT have to capture sensitive info on OUR servers.  The MODIFY action (NVP) supports the direct update of (sensitive) CC information.  This kinda defeats the purpose of using PayPal Advanced.

QUESTION:  How do we update (using the API) the payment info for an existing subscription profile that was converted using the "conversion" method.  Using PAYPAL ADVANCED with the RECURRING BILLING option.

Thx, Doc
Mon, 02/25/2013 - 10:59

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly there is not a way to do this using PayPal's hosted pages.  This may be something that is avaialble in the future, but at this time it is not.  The only options you would have at this time is using the API and performing the updates from your website (not using the hosted pages), or cancel the profile and send them back through the sign up flow to create a new profile once their information (credit card info) changes or expires.